# Google Places API - filter by contact fields

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

is there a way to filter Google Places API requests by contact fields?

I can filter by city, country, etc, but what if I want to filter by 'website'? How do I do that?

Note that I know I can filter it in my script but I don't want to waste time on places that doesn't have website.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get filtered results on contact fields (such as "website") through the Places API at this time.

However, you can file a Feature Request for this in Google's Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com

The Places API component can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188872)

Hope this helps!